# Unable to create the webapp using Azure CLI

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am using the below commands for creating the webapp  using Azure CLI but getting the below exception-

Unable to retrieve details of the existing app 'newapp2'. Please check that the app is a part of the current subscription

Command -
az webapp create --name newapp2000 --resource-group staging-grp --plan newappplan2000 --runtime "DOTNETCORE|3.1"

subscription- payasgo

Looking forward for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

1. A very effective way to check if your commands work or not is going to portal, login with your account, check if your web app exist in your subscription or not.
2. If you don't want to use portal, you could also use CLI commands. You should check if the session you are using linked to your subscription or not:

   ```
    az account show --output table
   ```

   If not, use this command to switch to a different subscription:

   ```
    az account set --subscription "My Demos"
   ```
3. You could also specify the subscription in the command while creating your web app:

   ```
    az webapp create --resource-group StorageGroups --subscription "My Demos" \
    --name newapp2000 --location eastus --plan newappplan2000 --runtime "DOTNETCORE|3.1"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Just like resource group, WebAapp name has to be globally unique. It could be that newapp2000 already exist

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftweb